# How to add button and respective event in groupheader of grouping grid ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I am using the Extjs4.2.1 
and  I want to add the Extjs Button in the groupHeader of GroupingGrid.

for the reference please have a look
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping

Answer (score 3):

groupHeader can be formatted using [groupHeaderTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-cfg-groupHeaderTpl), and add [groupclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-event-groupclick) listener to listen click events

Sample here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dq

Comment: Exactly the same thing I want , But I also want to bind some event on this button like opening the new window with passing some prameter. Can you please tell me how can I bind event into it.

Comment: This case click event can be traced in groupClick listener, pls check the console message in the fiddle ..

Answer (score 0):

Putting a real Ext button in the header would be hard... but you can add just about any html to the groupHeader via the [groupHeaderTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping-cfg-groupHeaderTpl).

Answer (score 0):

I added like this and it worked:

```
features: [{
    ftype: 'grouping',
    groupHeaderTpl: 'Job Premium Id: {name} <button type="button" onclick="set()">Click Me!</button> {sampleButton}',
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the html button in the groupHeaderTpl it worked fine.

features: [{
        ftype: 'grouping',
        groupHeaderTpl: 'Click Me! {sampleButton}',
    }],

Answer (score -2):

Refer to the EXT JS 4.2 examples by Sencha.
Please refer below example.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/remote-group-summary-grid.html

Comment: I want to add the Button near by group header name, not at docItems.